# Html view source encrypting

Tags: html, encryption

I had a lot of searching on Google but I didn't get the solution for encrypting Html source view from client view and client cant inspect element of my Html as well. For this problem is any body has a solution or any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Not possible. Your browser has to be able to read the source code to construct the page.

Comment: build your own browser that doesnt show the source. problem solved.

Comment: You can't. You can set a limited restrictions using JavaScript, like disabling right click, disabling some shortcut keys (used for opening inspection window).. But still, there are many ways remaining user can open inspection or view source window.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

The browser has to decode it in order to render it. The browser is designed for the convenience and security of the user, not the author of the page.

The browser will show a serialisation of the DOM back to HTML if the user desires it.